# Proving uniform continuity and uniform discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, epsilon-delta

Could someone please explain to me how to show uniform continuity and not uniformly continuous for the following:

> $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ for $A = [1, \infty)$ show uniform continuity
>
> $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ for $B = [0, \infty)$ show that $f$ is not uniformly continuous

Comment: Just FYI, the opposite of "uniformly continuous" is "not uniformly continuous," rather than "uniformly discontinuous."

Comment: oh thanks, now could you please tell me how to prove uniform continuity. I have been able to prove the "not uniform continuity" part but I am still stuck at the uniform continuity part

Comment: never mind I got the answer, thanks for the correction though

Comment: @BilalJunaidy If you got the answer, you can consider self answering your question. (You will get a hat as a reward!)

Answer (score 0):

Here we see that $$f’(x)=-\frac{2}{x^3}$$
In $A$, $-2\leq f’(x)<0$, that is bounded but in $B$, $f’(x)$ is not bounded. Therefore $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $A$ but not in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

1. $|\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}|\leq |\frac{y^2-x^2}{x^2y^2}|=|\frac{(y-x)(y+x)}{x^2y^2}|\leq |\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2}||y-x|\leq (|\frac{1}{xy^2}|+|\frac{1}{yx^2}|)|x-y|\leq 2|x-y|$

2.$\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not uniformly continuous. $|\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}|\leq |\frac{y^2-x^2}{x^2y^2}|$ Near $0$ quantity is very large.